# override master page, make content 100% width

Tags: css, asp.net, devexpress

Building an aspx child page as part of an existing solution.
I wanted to use the master page, because it includes the menu bar at the top of the content.

The problem is the content below is tradionally broken in to a left content, middle content, and right content.

I only want the below middle content and i want the width to be 100% wide.

Right now i have to blank columns on both sides, wasting valuable screen space.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SysDasbboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="SysDasbboard" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Dashboard.v18.1.Web.WebForms, Version=18.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.DashboardWeb" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onBeforeRender(s, e) {
            var dashboardControl = s.getDashboardControl();
            dashboardControl.registerExtension(registerCustomTreeView(dashboardControl));
        }
    </script>
    <dx:ASPxDashboard ID="ASPxDashboard1" runat="server" DashboardStorageFolder="~/App_Data/Dashboards" AllowExecutingCustomSql="True" EnableCustomSql="True">
     <ClientSideEvents BeforeRender="onBeforeRender" />
    </dx:ASPxDashboard>
    <script src="Scripts/CustomTreeViewExtension.js"></script>
    </asp:Content>
```

I've research and looked at related questions.  I sounds like i can add a  to override, but i can't quite get it.

Any help is greatly appredciated.

Comment: Can you visualize the current state and desired view? Is that `Dashboard` control required to show in fullscreen mode?

Comment: currently it's really compact.  i need the extra space to showcase all the widgets

Comment: Can you please add width='100%' to ASPxDashboard control either using inline style or attribute value

Comment: yea, i added width=100% to the dashboard, but i think the problem is it's doing 100% of the container that its in....  im trying to be lazy and not create or edit the master page but assume thats what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still learning CSS and MasterPages; i was trying to avoid editing the masterpage, but I found the resolution was just to create a new container in the masterpage and set its width there.   Then define the aspnet placeholder to that new container.